# Get a div when iterating through elements of a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33500718/1086511) I learned how to get the `form` that contains a `div`.

Now, let's say I want to clear all `divs` inside a `form` when I click the 'reset' button. When iterating through the elements of a form:

```
var F = some_form;
for (var i=0; i<F.elements.length; i++) {
    if (F.elements[i].id.substr(0,3) == 'div') {
        F.elements[i].innerHTML = '';
    }
}
```

I know that `divs` are not added as elements of containing `form`. Seems I'll need to get the `document` that contains the `form`, and then search for `divs` inside the `document`. That's slower, though. Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) to find `div` elements within the `form`:

```js
var F = document.getElementById('foo');

var divs = F.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; ++i)
  divs[i].innerHTML = '';
```

```html
<form action="" id="foo">
  <div>div</div>
  <div>another</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but... Very strange! I don't find any div using F.elements, but they are visible using F.getElementsByTagName? Is there any logic to it?

Comment: Yes - ["The HTMLFormElement.elements property returns an HTMLFormControlsCollection (HTML 4 HTMLCollection) of all the form controls contained in the FORM element, with the exception of input elements which have a type attribute of image."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements). A `div` is not a form control, nor would its contents be submitted as part of the form. It's unfortunate that the term "elements" is used both for form elements (the `.elements` property) and for any HTML element (`getElementsByTagName()`), but that's how it is.

Answer (score 1):

There as to be some iteration at some level. Have you assigned all the divs you wish to target a css class attribute?  If so you can iterate through them by `.getElementsByClassName('className')`.  EG.

```
var divs = some_form.getElementsByClassName('target'),
    dL = divs.length;
while(dL--) {
    divs[dL].innerHTML = '';
}
```

N.B. form`.elements` are targeted by `name` or `id` attributes.  See [MDN : HTMLFormElement.elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not styling them like that. I think the other answer is more straightforward.